# If a connected graph has a bridge then it has a cut vertex

Tags: graphs

Is it true that if a connected graph has a bridge then it has a cut vertex?

In my point of view, I don't think it is true to consider that a graph having a cut edge will definitely have cut vertex.

Consider a graph with a single edge $uv$; if we remove this edge, the graph will get disconnected but if we remove $u$, the graph will be connected as a graph with the single vertex is still consider connected.

Comment: It's true.  In fact, the graph with one vertex is sometimes considered disconnected.

Comment: So why do you doubt your answer?

Comment: @juho because if I answer wrong then in competitive exams I will be rewarded with negative marking :-) and secondly it is always better to discuss with a smart community.

Comment: @Pål GD if we take vertex connectivity into the picture then single vertex will be a trivial graph and is considered to be disconnected right?

Comment: @PålGD Really? I can't think of a single way to define connectivity that has a one-vertex graph disconnected. It's a universal property and any definition beginning "Every pair of distinct vertices" is vacuously true of the one-vertex graph. If you want to say something like "Every pair of not-necessarily-distinct vertices has a simple path between them" then you must accept paths with no edges, or trees aren't connected, so it's still true of the one-vertex graph.

Comment: @DavidRicherbyn this is what I cant understand, how a graph with a single vertex(Trivial graph) be disconnected?

Comment: @DavidRicherby It comes from [$k$-connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph), in which you require the graph to have _more than_ $k$ vertices.  By that definition ("a 1-connected graph is called connected"), $K_1$ is disconnected by having too few vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An edge $e=uv$ is a bridge in $G$ if there is no path between $u$ and $v$ in $G-e$.

In general, $u$ and $v$ are cut vertices, but there are some special cases you must treat with care.

(1) If $G \simeq K_2$, then depending on the definition of *connectivity*, the $G-u \simeq K_1$ might and might not be considered connected*.

(2) There is another case in which you would not consider $u$ to be a cut vertex; An edge  $uv$ is called a *pendant* edge if $\deg(u) = 1$.  In this case, if $uv$ is a pendant edge and $\deg(v)>1$, you would not typically call $u$ a cut vertex.

*Postlude*

All that being said, definitions in graphs are hard (case in point: Diestel).  When we try to make definitions very general, special cases sometimes become absurd.

*Note*

*1*

* To address David Richerby's objection, $K_1$ is considered *disconnected* when deriving connectivity from [k-connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph), in which you require the graph to have *more than $k$ vertices*. By that definition ("a 1-connected graph is called connected"), $K_1$ is disconnected by having too few vertices.

*2*

To answer Thinker's follow-up question; since you wanted to know what to answer to a hypothetical exam question, I would do it this way:

Let $e = uv$ be a bridge.  We have three cases:

1. $\deg(u), \deg(v) > 1$.  The statement is true.
2. $\deg(u) = 1, \deg(v) > 1$.  The statement is true, $e$ is a pendant.
3. $\deg(u) = \deg(v) = 1$.  The statement is true if and only if $K_1$ is considered connected.

Comment: So the statement, if a connected graph has a bridge then it has a cut vertex, does not hold for K2(a complete graph with 2 vertices ). by connected I mean 1-connected

Comment: @Thinker I answered you in an extra note in the answer.